# existence of a certain differentiable function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Claim: There is no differentiable function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\frac{1}{2}\le f'(x)\le 4$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-10$.

My attempt so far, but I don't get the whole idea: Suppose there exists such a function $f$. Then $f$ will be strictly monotonic increasing (because $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$) and there exists a $x <0$ such that $-10<f(x)<0$. Furthermore, we can apply the mean value theorem. Is it possible to lead the argumentation to a contradiction using this theorem?

Or other ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement

> ... there exists a $x <0$ such that $-10<f(x)<0$.

is not immediately obvious, but actually not needed.

For $x < 0$ the mean-value theorem applied to the interval $(x, 0)$ gives
$$
 f(0) - f(x) =  f'(c) \, (0 - x)\quad \text{for some } c \in (x, 0) \\
 \Longrightarrow f(x) = f(0) + f'(c)\,  x \le f(0) + \frac 12 x \\
  \Longrightarrow \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty
$$

which contradicts the assumption that $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-10$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MVT is useful for this problem.  The issue is that $f'(x)>1/2>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  This implies that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$.  Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to prove this:  For a every $T<0$ there exists an $N<0$ so that
$$
x<N\Rightarrow f(x) = f(0)-\int_x^0 f'(t)dt<T
$$

Comment: Sorry, I see in @Martin R answer you can use MVT.

Comment: Note that this would require that $f'$ is *integrable.*

Comment: Yes, you are right